# How to make Twitter XAuth post request data for access token?

Tags: twitter, http-post, xauth

When I had used following code, I got the message "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

```
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"]];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSString *postString = @"oauth_consumer_key=My Consumer key&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=My Consumer secret&oauth_timestamp=?????&oauth_nonce=?????oauth_version=1.0&x_auth_username=My Twitter ID&x_auth_password=My Twitter password&x_auth_mode=client_auth";
  [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

  NSHTTPURLResponse *response = NULL;
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
  NSString *responseDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  NSLog(@"Response from Twitter: %@", responseDataString);
```

So, I want to know exact configuration of request contents
The used post data as following. and My application had the ability to use xAuth

> oauth_consumer_key=My Consumer key
>
> oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
>
> oauth_signature=My Consumer secret
>
> oauth_timestamp=?????
>
> oauth_nonce=?????
>
> oauth_version=1.0
>
> x_auth_username=My Twitter ID
>
> x_auth_password=My Twitter password
>
> x_auth_mode=client_auth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read this. Hope it will help you.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth